# Backing up WhatsApp to two different Google Drive accounts

Tags: backup, whatsapp-messenger, google-account, google-drive

I have had my WhatsApp account backed up to my personal Google Drive account, taking up a total space of 841 MB. I now have access to a Drive account with more space, and I'd like to switch the backup to there.

I tried changing the settings on the phone to back up to the new account, but I only get 549 MB there.

Why would the two backups be so different? I'd like to delete the original one to free up space, but not if it means losing data.

Answer (score 0):

WhatsApp stores the last 7 backups. You can see it by checking your File manager -> WhatsApp -> databases and there, you can see almost 7 files. The size of files varies from each day.

Since you changed your Google account, only *the last backup file* will be stored in G Drive and previous backups will not be uploaded there. So, after 7 days, you can see that the size in G Drive becoming 841 MB.

Answer (score 0):

I've got a bit of experience in this and know exactly how it feels to lose chats. This method will consume a little data, but it's safe.

1. In WhatsApp, back up the chats again to save the latest ones (twice to be sure)
2. Open file manager copy the WhatsApp folder somewhere else (as a backup in case you messed anything up). Now you have 2 copies of the WhatsApp folder.
3. Go to Settings > Apps > WhatsApp > Storage > Clear data.
4. Log in to your WhatsApp account now (make sure it asks about the GDrive thing. accept it)
5. Restore the chats from the same (old) account. (This is because sometimes there is some syncing problem, the difference in size might be because of this)
6. After the backing up is done, go to Settings, change the Google account there and tap backup.